# Carttrhob update not working, version_compare incorrectly returns true for older version

Tags: cartthrob

Does anyone know how to update Cartthrob from version 2.3x to 2.4? It's not working for us. The system thinks our version is less than 2.02x.

Therefore older version database scripts seem to be run, removing necessary database columns such as member_id in cartthrob_sessions table and giving database errors. So this completely messed up our update on a live site, deleting required columns.

Comment: Please edit and post a specific question. If you're reporting a bug, please report directly to the addon developer.

Comment: The add on developer does not provide a suitable means to contact them not do they response. And I wanted to let others know about this issue.i have now edited do now please unhold so I can post our solution.

Comment: I appreciate your frustration but the EE Stack Exchange site isn't a place to warn or vent. That's why we have Twitter, no? Please limit posts to questions the community can help answer. Also, FYI... CartThrob is now offering phone support (free & paid + emergency paid) which may be what you are needing: http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_support/

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is not working? Even some screenshots describing the situation would be useful. When you say it's messed up your site, what has been messed up? Without a complete description of the problem, it's not possible for folks here to provide a solution.

Comment: I found the issue but had to change my post to a question only to unhold it, so I could then post my reply. I shall reply later.

Comment: And I have to disagree on a few things... I have found an issue and I think it is vital other people know. Cartthrob and EE no longer have forums. I do not need a callback from Carthrob. In fact I think there may be a joint issue with CT and EE due to version numbering and comparisons. There is no where other than thus website now for me to highlight this issue to other people. It is far more important issues like this are reported with solutions than silly rules.

Comment: As stated Adrian, the update thinks it's an older version. If your familiar with EE updates you know older update database queries will be executed which messes up the site due to missing database columns. My solution may explain it better. This is a serious issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the issue.

In the Cartthrob update this Expression Engine check returns true when comparing the update version to a much older 2.02xxx version:

```
version_compare($this->current, $version, '<');
```

So updating to 2.4 from 2.3 will execute updates associated with 2.02xxx.

It seems the EE version_compare script does not work when you have more than 2 digits after the dot.

So 2.02 works, 2.027 does not (or maybe it was 3 digits I cant remember).

This maybe a EE 2.7 issue, or Carttrhob using bad version numbers! I dont know.

In order for us to update Cartthrob we first had to restore an older database due to all the failed updates changes, then had to change the update script to remove any updates with "bad" version numbers.

I hope this post helps others due to no Cartthrob forum existing anymore.